# Getting MongoDB error on GCP instance, Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server, Please assist me

Tags: spring, mongodb, api, google-cloud-platform

When I run my Spring boot application on my own machine everything works fine. I decided to run it on a google cloud platform instance and now I am getting this error. I cant seem to figure it out and what is really making me confused is the fact that it works on my machine and not here.This is the last thing I need to do to get everything up and running and I cant figure it out

```
2020-06-09 20:28:31.980  INFO 1001 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01-ad9oa.mongodb.net:27017
    com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:580) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:445) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:299) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you are using App Engine flex which requires that some third party services like mLab for MongoDB need to connect via the service’s public IP address[missing] [1]. Meaning you may have to create a public IP and additional configurations with mLab, so you can pass the IP in the connection string on App Engine.

My suggestion is that you use Compute Engine to host your MongoDB which can be quickly deployed using Cloud Launcher [2]. This way they share the same private network and it is easier for them to interact. Information about deploying MongoDB on the Compute Engine can be accessed here [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-third-party-databases#other_cloud_providers

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-third-party-databases#hosting_on_compute_engine

[3] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-mongodb